# What's the alternative to IValueFormatter in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

So I started using AutoMapper for my ASP.NET MVC project, looked at a couple of examples and wrote my first IValueFormatter implementation when a blue wiggly popped up for IValueFormatter: Interface 'AutoMapper.IValueFormatter' is obsolete: "Formatters should not not be used". Well, okay, then how am I supposed to e.g. convert a DateTime to, say, a string?

Comment: Quick search in google gives: https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters

Comment: automapper has moved to [github - Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

Comment: Are these values meant to be used in MVC views or JSON?

Answer (score 4):

Just create mapping for the property without using IValueFormatter. For example:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DbItem, ItemView>()                  
    .ForMember(item => item.DateCreated, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(i => {
        var date = i.DateCreated;
        return date.ToShortDateString();                      
    }));
```

Instead of :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DbItem, ItemView>().ForMember(item => item.DateCreated, 
item => item.AddFormatter<ItemDateCreatedFormater>());
```

Comment: Actually, this is the solution that is currently working for me. If I use a ValueResolver instead that does the exact same thing in its ResolveCore method, I run into the whole Entity Framework proxy classes trouble. I tried to remedy that using Project().To() but more exceptions popped up by the minute and the messages from those exceptions aren't helpful at all.